# Error while calling Sabre CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ -- NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED

Tags: sabre

I am getting following error when I use `CreatePassengerNameRecordRS`.

```xml
<CreatePassengerNameRecordRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2">
         <ApplicationResults status="Complete" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01">
            <Success timeStamp="2018-09-01T17:13:20.180-05:00"/>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-09-01T17:13:08.870-05:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">EnhancedAirBookRQ: NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED</Message>
                  <Message code="53">NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED</Message>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-09-01T17:13:19.407-05:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.NOT AUTH.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</Message>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-09-01T17:13:19.470-05:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">EndTransactionLLSRQ: SEGMENTS NOT IN DATE ORDER - VERIFY AND REENTER</Message>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
         </ApplicationResults>
```

Comment: Can you please also post your enhanced airbook request? Depending on the route you either have to put in a ARUNK segment or turn on automated sorting in the TJR

Comment: This might help [Revalidate Itinerary Error Messages](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMax_Help/Content/Features/RevalidateItinerary/Revalidate_Error_Messages.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to your itinerary. At the end you can see SEGMENTS NOT IN DATE ORDER - VERIFY AND REENTER so it means that your itinerary is not properly arranged.

Is the source of availability (BFM, availability itself) returning this itinerary like this? Have you checked the itinerary marriage indicators?